# Haskell own replicate with first list-comprehension and then with recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

have to write functions with the same effekt like the replicate-function.

1. List comprehension:

My try:

```
rep list = [ a | a <- list, _ <- [1..a]]
```

Works great with Ints, but I want to use this with chars too. 
Something like this:

```
rep 4 "Hello"   => "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"
```

2 Recursion:

```
rep :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a]  
rep n x  
    | n <= 0    = []  
    | otherwise = x:rep (n-1) x
```

Same Problems with chars!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For list comprehension, this should work:

```
rep :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> t -> [t]
rep num list = [ a | a <- [list], _ <- [1..num]]
```

Or in a more efficient and nice form (Thanks to @chi):

```
rep num list = [ list | _ <- [1..num]]
```

Demo:

```
λ> rep 3 3
[3,3,3]
λ> rep 3 "hello"
["hello","hello","hello"]
```

Your recursive program works fine for me in both cases.

Comment: `[ a | a <- [list], _ <- [1..num]]` can be rewritten as `[ list | _ <- [1..num]]`